# openai python seems to be only generating the same image from openai.Image.create_edit

Tags: python, openai-api

When calling the openai.Image.create_edit function and sending for a edit to an existing picture with a mask it seems to only generate the same image that I submit.

```
import os
import openai
class OpenAIConnect:
    def OpenAIConnectToSource():
        openai.organization = "###"
        openai.api_key = "#######"
```

---

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from Global.DaleAuth import OpenAIConnect
import openai

OpenAIConnect.OpenAIConnectToSource() # connection to openai with organization and api_key

class UploadFormV2:

    def UploadAndRetrieve(self, imageInsert = None):
        image = Image.open('otters2.png')
        ConvertImage("image",imageInsert)
        transparentimagtest = Image.open('mask.png')
        ConvertImage("transparent",transparentimagtest)

        response = openai.Image.create_edit(
          image=open("image.png",'rb'),
          mask= open("transparent.png",'rb'),
          prompt="baby sea otter wearing a hat",
          n=2,
          size="1024x1024"
        )
        image_url = response['data']
        print(image_url)
        return(image_url)
    
    # resizes and formats images for submission 
    def ConvertImage(imageName, imageData):
        image = imageData
        print(image.size)
        image = imageData
        image = image.resize((1024, 1024),Image.ANTIALIAS) 
        image = image.convert('RGBA')
        image.save(imageName+'.png')
```

The image.png submitted [image: The submission image]

The mask used
[image: Mask Used]

The results returned (screenshot due to file size limitations) [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not how this works, the masks needs to represent the area of the image which may be edited by the AI, for example if u want the otter to wear glasses then u need to create a mask which needs to have blank alpha channel around the eyes of the otter. If u want the otter to wear a hat than u need to create a mask which includes a blank spot on the top of the head of the otter.